# Можно ли создать подобие iframe на php?

Tags: php, парсер

Есть кабинет пользователя, написанный на `python`. Возможно ли внедрить его в существующий дизайн (наподобие как через `iframe`), чтобы отображалось внутри страницы, только на `php`?
Даже не знаю, в каком направлении гуглить... `cUrl` получается загрузить страницу, но еще нужно и передавать данные (допустим форма авторизации)

Или это нереально?

Answer (score 1):

Можно AJAX-ом запрашивать PHP-роуты для получения данных и отправки POST/PUT-запросов. Единственная проблема, если вы перехватываете все сообщения для домена и реализуете роутинг на уровне python-приложения. Как вариант, можно создать домен третьего уровня phpapi.yoursite.ru и разместить PHP-приложение на нем.

Comment: идею не понял...размещу на поддомене и что дальше?

Comment: Далее модифицируете JavaScript-логику приложения так, чтобы оно могло обращаться и к python и php-частям приложения.

Comment: А может как-то реализовать это через .htaccess?